# Getting smaller size of image when captured from camera in Android

Tags: android, image, camera

In my android application when I capture image from camera, I want to re-size it's dimensions. I am successful to re-size, when I take image from gallery. But when I capture from camera, I failed. Please help

```
if (requestCode == take_image &&  resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
    thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
    image2 = me1;
    addattachmentsToListView(image2);
}
```

Here is the code to resize image from sdcard:

```
if (requestCode == UploadFile && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    try {

        Bitmap image=(decodeUri(selectedImage));
        addattachmentsToListView(image);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
    getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;

    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp / 1.5 &lt; REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 1.5 &lt; REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            break;
        }
        width_tmp /= 4;
        height_tmp /= 4;

        //   width_tmp = 20;
        // height_tmp = 20;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
    getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);
}
```

Comment: Are you saving the image on the device or you want to resize the frame you get from the camera?

Comment: @fasteque i want to resize the frame

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799901/creating-dcf-thumbnail-from-jpeg you scale the image in bmp and create the scalled JPG again.

Answer (score 0):

In your `public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)`, you could get a bitmap in this way:

```
Bitmap bmp = YUVtoBMP(data, ImageFormat.NV21, YOUR_CAMERA_SIZE);

public Bitmap YUVtoBMP(byte[] data, int format, Camera.Size size)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(data, format, size.width, size.height, null);
    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, size.width, size.height), 50, out);
    byte[] imageBytes = out.toByteArray();
    Options options = new Options();
    options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = false;
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length, options);

    return image;
}
```

In order to scale a bitmap, you can:

```
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, NEW_WIDTH, NEW_HEIGHT, true);
```

This is just a hint: start from this and try to look for optimization if any.